# can't select a range for hr element with nth-of-type

Tags: html, css

the 1st hr to the 3rd hr element should be red, but its not, can someone tell me why?

```css
hr:nth-of-type(n+1):nth-of-type(-n+3){
background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<hr />
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works as it should. Increase the height of `hr`, you will see the effect. And don't stack nth-of-type, the last one will rule all

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `border` property instead:

```
border:1px solid red;
```

```css
hr:nth-of-type(n+1):nth-of-type(-n+3){
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<hr />
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify border, not background and set the HR as constants, not formulas, because they're intended to select items by other methods.

```css
hr:nth-of-type(1), hr:nth-of-type(3){
border:1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<hr>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type